# How to get print the content of tags in order in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, html, regex, module, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the text from an html page posted below. I tried for loops but it does not print the strings in order. I need to print the strings in order like:

```
            text1:text_1.1
            text2:text2.2,2.2
            ...
```

I need to get the output printed above.

```html
<ul> 
   <li>
    <b>text1:</b>
    <a><a href="search.php?origin=">text_1.1</a>
    </li>
   <li>
    <b>text2</b>
    <a href="search.php?origin=">text_2.1</a>
    <a href="search.php?origin">text_2.2</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <b>text4</b>
    <a href="search.php?origin=">text_4.1</a>
    <a href="search.php?origin=">text_4.2</a>
    <a href="search.php?origin=">text_4.3</a>
    <a href="search.php?origin=">text_4.4</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <b>text5</b>
     <a href="search.php?origin=">text5.1</a>
   </li>
    <li>
    <b>text6</b>
    <a href="search.php?origin=">text6.1</a>
    <a href="search.php?origin=">text6.2</a>
    <a href="search.php?origin=">text6.3</a>
   <li>
    <b>text7</b>
    <a href="search.php?origin=">text7.1</a>
    <font color="green">text7.2</font>          
    </li>
   <li>
    <b>text8</b>
    <a href="dwres.php?resource=">2 </a>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Your edit makes no sense, where is  `text2:text2.2,2.2` coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find all `<li>` elements so you can group their contents by the `<b>` tags. You probably want a dictionary to map them, but to preserve the document order you could use an `collections.OrderedDict()` object perhaps:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

results = OrderedDict()

for li in soup.find_all('li'):
    bold = li.b
    if bold is None:
        continue
    results[bold.get_text(strip=True)] = [
        link.get_text(strip=True) for link in li.find_all('a')
    ]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
...     <ul> 
...        <li>
...         <b>text1:</b>
...         <a><a href="search.php?origin=">text_1.1</a>
...         </li>
...        <li>
...         <b>text2</b>
...         <a href="search.php?origin=">text_2.1</a>
...         <a href="search.php?origin">text_2.2</a>
...        </li>
...        <li>
...         <b>text4</b>
...         <a href="search.php?origin=">text_4.1</a>
...         <a href="search.php?origin=">text_4.2</a>
...         <a href="search.php?origin=">text_4.3</a>
...         <a href="search.php?origin=">text_4.4</a>
...        </li>
...        <li>
...         <b>text5</b>
...          <a href="search.php?origin=">text5.1</a>
...        </li>
...         <li>
...         <b>text6</b>
...         <a href="search.php?origin=">text6.1</a>
...         <a href="search.php?origin=">text6.2</a>
...         <a href="search.php?origin=">text6.3</a>
...        <li>
...         <b>text7</b>
...         <a href="search.php?origin=">text7.1</a>
...         <font color="green">text7.2</font>          
...         </li>
...        <li>
...         <b>text8</b>
...         <a href="dwres.php?resource=">2 </a>
...       </ul>
... ''')
>>> results = OrderedDict()
>>> for li in soup.find_all('li'):
...     bold = li.b
...     if bold is None:
...         continue
...     results[bold.get_text(strip=True)] = [
...         link.get_text(strip=True) for link in li.find_all('a')
...     ]
... 
>>> results
OrderedDict([(u'text1:', [u'', u'text_1.1']), (u'text2', [u'text_2.1', u'text_2.2']), (u'text4', [u'text_4.1', u'text_4.2', u'text_4.3', u'text_4.4']), (u'text5', [u'text5.1']), (u'text6', [u'text6.1', u'text6.2', u'text6.3']), (u'text7', [u'text7.1']), (u'text8', [u'2'])])
>>> for key, elems in results.items():
...     print '{}: {}'.format(key, ', '.join(elems))
... 
text1:: , text_1.1
text2: text_2.1, text_2.2
text4: text_4.1, text_4.2, text_4.3, text_4.4
text5: text5.1
text6: text6.1, text6.2, text6.3
text7: text7.1
text8: 2
```

The `print` could just be integrated into the loop, but by building a dictionary you can now do further processing; writing it to a file, sending it somewhere else, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

for t in BeautifulSoup(html).find("ul").find_all("a"):
    print(t.text)
```

Output:

```
text_1.1
text_2.1
text_2.2
text_4.1
text_4.2
text_4.3
text_4.4
text5.1
text6.1
text6.2
text6.3
text7.1
```

If you want both the a and b tag text:

```
ul = BeautifulSoup(html).find("ul")
b=  [b.text for  b in ul.find_all("b")]
a = [a.text for  a in ul.find_all("a")]
```

You will need to decide on how you want the output matched up you as there are obviously more a tags then b.

You can also get the li tags and access the a and b tags using join to get somewhat close to what you seem to want:

```
ul = BeautifulSoup(html).find("ul")
li = ul.find_all("li")

for ele in li:
    print("{}:{}".format(ele.b.text,"".join([a.text for a in ele.find_all("a")])))
text1::text_1.1
text2:text_2.1text_2.2
text4:text_4.1text_4.2text_4.3text_4.4
text5:text5.1
text6:text6.1text6.2text6.3
text7:text7.1
text8:2
```

Comment: @emilgeorgejames, added an example at the end.

Comment: code gives me  following Attribute error :   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: You will obviously have to find the correct ul tag, I don't have the html so I cannot tell you exactly what to use, what is the url you are parsing? If that is the element returned then search that element.